# How can I apply rewrite rules to HTML files included in an ASP.NET project?

Tags: asp.net, azure, url-rewriting

I have a project I've built using ASP.NET. I'm including flat files HTML in the project that others have built. There are no controllers associated with these pages.

I'm trying to redirect HTTP to HTTPS on all pages. Having been buffedled with web.config rewrite rules that seemingly failed to apply, I finally implemented the following code in global.asax as a last resort:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
            {
                Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
            + HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
            }
        }
```

Now, when I load the site using `http://www.example.com` I'm redirected to `https://www.example.com`, hooray!

Except I can still navigate to the other pages using HTTP...

It seems the rules apply only when navigating to the domain alone, and any of my API controllers.

I still have rewrite rules in the web.config:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Enforce SSL" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="/?(secure.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But these aren't applying to the files I've included in the project.

How can I apply rewrite rules to flat HTML files I've included in my project?

<sub>For what it's worth, this is going on an Azure Web Site role.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a rewrite rule wizard, but enabled="false" on the rule definition looks suspicious.

This works for me (inside system.webServer):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action 
          type="Redirect" 
          url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" 
          appendQueryString="true"
          redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Credit to Maarten Balliauw (http://blog.maartenballiauw.be) who shared this with me a while back.

Comment: Oops. After a couple tries I ended up resorting to copy-pasta. That was the latest. Changed to `true` but still no luck.